# Apple's SpeedSketch example app is very laggy

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to create an app which uses the Apple Pencil (or just a finger) to draw/sketch/write on a blank "sheet" on the iPad. Last WWDC there was a session which shows how the Apple Pencil should be used inside an app.

Here's a link to this session: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/220/
(You can download the example app there.)

When you start to draw something it works really great. But after a while, if you have drawn a lot, it gets really laggy and I don't know why. I want to use this code inside my app to be able to use the pencil, but I can't use it like that, because it get's really annoying when you want to draw something and it takes some time until the line is showing up.

There is the following comment in `CGDrawingEngine.swift`:

```
/**
    Note: this is not a particularily efficient way to draw a great stroke path
    with CoreGraphics. It is just a way to produce an interesting looking result.
    For a real world example you would reuse and cache CGPaths and draw longer
    paths instead of an aweful lot of tiny ones, etc. You would also respect the 
    draw rect to cull your draw requests. And you would use bezier paths to
    interpolate between the points to get a smooother curve.
 */
```

It would be very nice if you could try to understand what's exactly happening and why it is very slow after some time and how to change the code according to Apple's comment on the drawing function.

(PS: I should mention that this example app is only running on iOS10 Beta with Swift 3.0)

**EDIT**: I'm testing this app on an iPad Pro (12.9") with iOS10 Beta 5.

Comment: Is it on an actual iPad pro? If yes then what is the memory and cpu statuses? Sorry do not have an iPad pro to test with myself.

Comment: Edited my question @StephenKac.